# bootstrap 4 pull/float-right not working with psd

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a psd. I've tried to design it. but I was not successful.

I want to design with `bootstrap 4.3.1` as follow.

[image: PSD]

But I see this.

[image: Sample]

This is the code.

```html
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white pt-4 pb-4">
            <div class="justify-content-start float-right">
                <h3>140</h3>
                <p>Users</p>
            </div>
            <h1 class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example with just bootstrap / font awesome on the structure though there's multiple ways to accomplish the same, you'll probably need to tweak the example for your usage, cheers.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<br/>

<div class="container-fluid border rounded w-50 shadow-sm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto bg-success text-white d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-3 px-5 rounded-left">
      <i class="fas fa-user h1"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right p-2 pb-5 pr-3">
      Users<br/>
      <span class="font-weight-bold h5">123</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```